# How do I fix the "Cannot retrieve repository metadata" error in Fedora 14?

Tags: fedora, yum

When I try to install anything on Fedora 14, I get the following output:

> Repository base is listed more than once in the configuration
>
> Could not retrieve mirrorlist
> http://s2plmirror01.prod.sdl2.secureserver.net/vph/2/download/mirrors/fedora-core-14
>
> error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "" Error: Cannot retrieve repository
> metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and
> try again

Answer (score 1):

The URL times out for me as well. I suggest changing your mirror. See the following list of [Fedora 14 Mirrors](http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/14/).